# FFMPEG command created a file that I can't delete or rename. If I try to do either of those windows explorer stops responding

Tags: ffmpeg, video, windows-11

Using windows 11. I was trying to merge a png image and a wav file into a video for youtube using `ffmpeg`. The command I used was:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mov
```

It worked great, but the .mov file that was created is like some monster that can't be destroyed or affected. If I try to rename it or delete it, file explorer stops responding indefinitely. And ever since I ran this command and created the file, file explorer has been slower to start up, and I also can't rename the folder that the file is in without the same problem happening where file explorer freezes indefinitely. Right-clicking the file also takes a very long time.

So I can play the video, and it is perfect, but it seems to be affecting file explorer globally, so that's the main problem. I'm assuming the file is responsible.

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder where the file is through command line, next use the del command to delete the file

```
cd Folder
del /q /a out.mov
```

Comment: The demon has been slain. Thank you sir.

Comment: Now I might be imagining things, but it seems to me that file explorer is still slower to load everything upon opening it than it was before. It used to be instantaneous, but now it takes a couple seconds. Did I damage my computer or something?

Comment: Okay I tried a different ffmpeg command to do the same thing and it created another file with the same problem. Except this time your command isn't working on it. I guess I just shouldn't use ffmpeg anymore.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I just needed to uncheck read-only on the folder it was in. But then how come I could delete or modify the names of every other file in it and not that one? And my question in my second comment still stands.

Comment: you could try this on the command line it fixes several windows errors do to missing or corrupted files: sfc /scannow

Comment: I did try that before and everything was good. I just fixed the slow file explorer problem by going to options within file explorer, unchecking all the boxes in the "privacy" section (show recently used files, show frequently used folders, and show files from office.com) and cleared file explorer history. It's back to opening nearly instantaneously again.